# Asus q400A wireless drivers

Tags: wireless, laptop, asus

So i have Ubuntu 12.04 on my Asus Q400A it all looks fine but the wireless drivers are missing i have tried installing the Intel Drivers from the repository but nothing. suggestions or solutions will be greatly appreciated thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I had a wireless driver problem on my ASUS 1015e recently, this blog post solved it for me.

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1368699.

I'm not sure if you've got broadcom hardware or not, but if you do this should fix it.